# Find specified position's value on a function decleration

Tags: regex

I try to find method(function) declerations on which 6th argument is `true`. Actually I think I can return ,just using regex, wished group without using an extra programming language's feature, unfortunately no option exits as such.

```
sdfsdfs(123,234,werer,23324,234324,true,dwfwefwer,sdfdsdff);
sdfsdfs(123,234,true,23324,234324,true,dwfwefwer);
sdfsdfs(123,234,234234,23324,234324,r23423,dwfwefwer);
sdfsdfs(123,234,234234,23324,234324,false,dwfwefwer);
(123,234,werer,23324,234324,true,dwfwefwer,sdfdsdff)
erterterterter(123,234,werer,23324,234324,true,dwfwefwer,sdfdsdff);
```

What I have tried is [here](https://regex101.com/r/FQoaPA/). `(\b\w+(?=\s*[,()]))`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/FQoaPA/3, something like `^\w*\([^(),]+,[^(),]+,[^(),]+,[^(),]+,[^(),]+,true,[^()]*\);?$` could help.

Comment: You could use a quantifier `\w*\([^(),]+(?:,[^(),]+){4},true(?:,[^(),]+)*\);?` See https://regex101.com/r/4AfcXN/1

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following regex.

```
(?i)\w*\([^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,true\b,[^\)]+\)
```

I have done here https://regex101.com/r/BEJNp4/1/